# How to show a location in SQL Server in Google maps

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, google-maps

I have a table in the SQL Server database which holds some longitude and latitude values I want to show them in a google map in the asp.net website

Any links or help will be appreciated.

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should check out the [Google maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/)

Comment: they only say about the javascript not the server side